# Cannot align the innerHTML of a span vertically in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, sass

I'm having an issue getting a spans' inner text to be vertically centered on Firefox

Here's a screenshot of the firefox devtools highlighting the span element.

[image: dev tools highlight]

This Works as expected on Chrome and Safari.

```html
            <button
              style={{ marginTop: this.state.marginTop }}
              className={`info-tab-title`}
            >
              <img
                className="tab-icon"
                src="/images/neighborhood/train.svg"
                alt="train icon"
              />
              <span>TO BROOKLYN</span>
            </button>
```

```css
    .info-tab {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: #e5e8ea;
      padding: 2% 4% 4% 4%;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 100%;
      max-height: calc(16.67% - 6px);
      transition: 0.25s max-height ease-in-out;
      &:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
      .info-tab-title {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: flex-start;
        font-family: 'BrownStd Regular';
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 0.35px;
        line-height: 16px;
        min-height: 26px !important;
        align-items: center;
        @media #{$mobile-break} {
          font-size: 14px;
        }
        .tab-icon {
          margin-right: 2.5%;
          height: 100%;
          width: auto;
        }
      }
}
```

Ideally, the text would be vertically centered inside the span.

***This is not a duplicate, the suggested answers are all addressing aligning two elements in a parent. This is referring to a browser specific problem with aligning the innerHTML content of a span.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing all right. Font metrics of BrownStd cause this issue. The distance from symbol baseline to bottom of font content area is bigger than distance to top. 
Not sure you can perfectly align text and icon without some tricks like **negative margins** or **absolute positioning**. 
You can read this [article about font metrics](http://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align), it's pretty hard to understand.

```css
button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

span {
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Nice font —</h1>

<button>

  <div></div>
  <span>nice vertical alignment</span>

</button>
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/3rdthemagical/pen/byJJNw) with custom BrownStd font.

Comment: But if this is an issue with the font how come the problem only exists on certain browsers?

Comment: @SpencerFink I think browsers have different algorithms for font rendering.

Comment: Win10, latest Edge, FF & Chrome — https://i.imgur.com/IEf0oOt.png Not perfect alignment.

Answer (score 0):

If by "innerHTML content of a span" you're referring to the bounding box of the text, I believe the only way to manipulate that in CSS is via `line-height`, and you can't change how the text is aligned within its line-height.

In this case, I would try reducing the line-height to the exact height of the text, and then `align-items: center` on the parent should work.